# Difference between "difficult" and "hard"

Tags: differences, adjectives

According to **[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)**

[**Difficult**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/difficult?s=t)

> **difficult**
> [dif-i-kuhlt, -kuh lt]
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. not easily or readily done; requiring much labor, skill, or planning to be performed successfully; hard
>
> *a difficult job.*
>
> 2. hard to understand or solve
>
> *a difficult problem.*
>
> 3.hard to deal with or get on with
>
> *a difficult pupil.*

**[Hard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hard?s=t)**

> **hard**[hahrd]
>
> **adjective**, harder, hardest.
>
> 1.not soft; solid and firm to the touch; unyielding to pressure and impenetrable or almost impenetrable.
>
> 2.firmly formed; tight
>
> *a hard knot.*
>
> 3.difficult to do or accomplish; fatiguing; troublesome
>
> *a hard task.*
>
> etc. (many more)

In what situations is there a preference over the other? What are the rules for that?

Comment: *Difficult* comes from Latin, and *hard* comes from German.  *Difficult* has a narrower meaning.  Other than that, it depends on context and what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: In what context? Also, do you want to know the difference in meaning, the difference in how they sound, the difference in who uses them, or what? I think you're going to have to be more specific...

Comment: I edited according to your questions. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: 'Hard' can _usually_ be used in place of 'difficult' in sentences 2 & 7. But we'd probably say 'this job is hard' rather than 'this is a hard job'; 'the operation was performed under the hardest **of** conditions' ... // This question is far too broadly scoped, but does serve to illustrate well the vast chasm between 'synonymous' and 'always interchangeable'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The sentences under the different definitions aren't mine. I got all that from dictionary.com. My example sentences are at the bottom

Comment: They're interchangeable in your example sentences But sadly, (a) they may not be in the next sentence you come across; (b) the dictionary tries its best, but doesn't cover all allowable sentences (it can't, of course). Slight changes may render one word a poor or even bad choice. 'This terrain is difficult.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Will you put that in an answer with maybe some example sentences where they're not interchangeable.

Comment: No. Look through the lists of definitions and check where senses are unique. eg **hard 7**. performing or carrying on work with great effort, energy, or persistence: _a hard worker_. No corresponding sense given for **difficult**; _a difficult worker_ uses **difficult** sense 3. 'Difficult luck' is unacceptable. Even within senses, collocations are restricted: **hard** 8.vigorous or violent in force _a hard rain_ / _a hard fall_ / [_a hard tackle_] / [*_a hard tornado_].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I feel like I am repeating myself. Those aren't MY sentences, they're the dictionary's sentences. I am also quite surprised that you didn't want to receive any credit for your comment as an answer.

Comment: I've already close-voted for being **far** too broad (if the dictionary takes so many lines in its only-reasonable attempt, what would an exhaustive answer look like?). I didn't say those were your sentences. I said analyse the sentences the dictionary gives **yourself**.

Comment: @sumelic Is it ok now? can it be put off hold now that I changed my question and specified it more?

Comment: @anonymous: oh, why did you delete the example sentences?

Comment: @sumelic It didn't relate to the new specified question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good answers have already been given and accepted, but I'll just add that the word "difficult" might be seen as slightly more formal and/or sophisticated than "hard" in some contexts. I would lean toward "difficult" in formal writing. "Hard" can come across as a bit rough and workmanlike, so to speak.

Comment: Perfectly said! Can you provide me with some examples of the different circumstances of preferred hard and difficult?

Comment: Hm, I'll try! As an example, in a formal article I'd expect to see something like—"All involved acknowledge that the unrest in the Middle East will be difficult to resolve." "Hard" would work there, but it's a little less sophisticated—at least to my ear. It's a subtle distinction, though—and one that may not matter much generally.

Answer (score 1):

They are interchangeable a lot of the time as their meanings overlap. As someone else said they have different origins and the totality of their meanings are different.

Some examples of non-interchangeable sentences:

The rock is a hard, solid object.

Susan was being very difficult while talking with her counselor about what happened on Saturday.

Comment: Of course, the rock could be difficult, if it is in a bad place and you're trying to move it.  And Susan can be hard (cold and unemotional) while talking to her counselor.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure you could describe a rock as difficult in a different sentence and with different context. But not in this one. As for the susan one, the word difficult and hard could both be used, but they bring slightly (but significant enough) different meanings.